# How to refresh a single row in a table?

Tags: java, vaadin

Is it possible to refresh a single row of a **vaadin** `table` component?

So far, if table row editing is finished, I'm just refreshing the whole table:

`table.refreshRowCache();`

But that will probably cause performance issues later for large tables. So, how could a single row be refreshed?

Comment: What is your use case? Vaadin's data binding should automatically notify the table about changes in the data model. In some rare cases, it is however needed to call refreshRowCache manually. And no, there is no way to re-render one specific row in the table.

Comment: A usecase could be the editing of a single table entry. Which guarantees that it would be sufficient to only refresh this single row, instead of a whole (maybe large) table. The same applies when adding single items to the table.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115437/in-vaadin-7-0-how-to-refresh-javabean-data-backing-a-table-replace-container

There are a bunch of solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this on the Vaadin forum which seems useful: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/408555/408554

I haven't yet given it a go but, Henri Sara (Vaadin developer) suggested this solution:

```
Property statusProperty = pqTable.getContainerProperty(itemId, "statusString");
if (property instanceof MethodProperty) {
    ((MethodProperty) statusProperty).fireValueChange();
}
```

He also notes that this method may change in a future version (and may have done so already :S)

Answer (score 0):

1.update your `beanItemContainer`

2.`table.refreshRowCache();`

Example:

```
beanItemContainer.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("quantity").setValue(productEditor.getProduct().getQuantity());
table.refreshRowCache();
```