# Data changes made internally in a bean disappear when user edits bean via FieldGroup and BeanContainer in Vaadin 7 app

Tags: java, containers, vaadin, vaadin7

## Disappearing Data

Say I have a `Person` class with member variables 'name' and 'modified'. The `setName` setter updates the 'modified' variable with a fresh date-time value. Good.

When I put such beans in a Vaadin BeanContainer, display that container in a Table, and let the user edit through a FieldGroup subwindow, the 'name' change sticks but the 'modified' change appears briefly in the debugger before disappearing again. Poof! Gone. I see the 'name' field’s fresh value instantly appear in the Table, but not the new 'modified' value. Bad.

## Solutions That Don’t Work

I tried some supposed solutions, but they don't work.

### `MethodProperty::fireValueChange()`

I read the Vaadin Forums thread, [refresh row in table based on BeanItemContainer?](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/408555/408554). I tried the suggested code like the following, but that did not work.

```
Property property = this.table.getContainerProperty( this.itemId , Person.PROPERTY.NAME );
if ( property instanceof MethodProperty ) {
    ( ( MethodProperty ) property ).fireValueChange();
}
```

## Table Refresh

I also tried a plain old call to refresh the Table. But no go.

```
this.table.refreshRowCache();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

Your data change is not disappearing. Your data change is being overwritten. That’s a feature, not a bug.

Solution: Make the 'modified' member variable read-only by changing the scope of its setter from `public` to `private`.

## Details

The FieldGroup object’s job, when its `commit()` method is called, is to take the current values found in the buffered Field objects, compare those values to the current values in the backing bean, and update the bean with any found differences.

The FieldGroup thinks of itself as the boss. It assumes all your data changes are going through the Vaadin Data Model. When the bean’s internal method (the setter) updates another member variable ('modified' in this case), that change is made while going behind the back of the FieldGroup. The FieldGroup does not know you intend that internal change to be official data on record. Instead, the FieldGroup dutifully sees a mismatch between the bean's value and the buffered Field value, and proceeds to fix that mismatch by overwriting the fresh 'modified' variable's value with the old value stored in the Field’s buffer. Feature, not a bug.

## Demo

Here is a complete example Vaadin app to show this process. The source code here is long, but I   could not think of a way to make it shorter while still being clearly understandable.

To see the demonstration:

1. Run the app.
2. Select a row in the table.
3. Click the "Edit" button.
4. In the detail form that appears in the subwindow, edit the Person 'Name' field.
5. Click the "Commit" button.
6. Switch to your IDE debugger, and study the output.

Note how the Person class called the `setModified` method from inside the `setName` method. The bean does have a fresh date-time value at that moment. Then a moment later the FieldGroup called the `setModified` method again

### Example App

Create a new Vaadin 7.3 app named `EditListInVaadin`.

Add one dependency, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Joda-Time makes date-time work easier, but you could replace the `DateTime` objects with java.util.Date objects if you insist on avoiding this dependency.

#### `MyVaadinUI.java`

Replace the MyVaadinUI.java with the following.

```
package com.example.editlistinvaadin;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.data.Item;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanContainer;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Theme ( "mytheme" )
@SuppressWarnings ( "serial" )
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI
{
    List<Person> personList = null;
    BeanContainer<String , Person> personBeanContainer = null;
    Table personTable = null;
    Button editPersonButton = null;
    VerticalLayout layout = null;

    @WebServlet ( value = "/*" , asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( productionMode = false , ui = MyVaadinUI.class , widgetset = "com.example.editlistinvaadin.AppWidgetSet" )
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest request )
    {
        this.layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin( true );
        layout.setSpacing( true );

        this.personList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.personList.add( new Person( "Susan" ) );
        this.personList.add( new Person( "Ingrid" ) );
        this.personList.add( new Person( "Pierre" ) );
        this.personList.add( new Person( "François" ) );

        this.personBeanContainer = new BeanContainer<>( Person.class );
        this.personBeanContainer.setBeanIdProperty( Person.PROPERTY.UUID );    // Use the name property as the item ID of the bean
        this.personBeanContainer.addAll( this.personList ); // Feed the beans to the container.
        this.personTable = new Table( "Person" , personBeanContainer ); // Present the bean container in a table.
        this.personTable.setSelectable( true );
        //this.personTable.setPageLength( this.personBeanContainer.size() );
        layout.addComponent( this.personTable );

        this.editPersonButton = new Button( "Edit" );
        this.editPersonButton.addClickListener( ( Button.ClickEvent event ) -> {
            editPerson();
        } );
        layout.addComponent( this.editPersonButton );

        this.setContent( layout );
    }

    private void editPerson ()
    {
        // Fetch the data to be displayed in detail.
        Object itemId = this.personTable.getValue();  // Get id of item currently selected by user.
        Item item = this.personBeanContainer.getItem( itemId );
        Window window = new PersonDetailWindow( itemId , item , this.personBeanContainer , this.personTable );
        window.setModal( true );
        window.center();
        window.addCloseListener( ( Window.CloseEvent e ) -> {
            // Dump original data.
            System.out.println( "Original data [-----" );
            for ( Person p : this.personList ) {
                System.out.println( "person bean: " + p.toString() ); // Notice the new 'modified' value is lost.
            }
            System.out.println( "----]" );
        } );
        this.addWindow( window );
    }

}
```

Then add two more class files shown below: `Person.java` and `PersonDetailWindow.java`.

#### `Person.java`

```
package com.example.editlistinvaadin;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class Person implements Serializable
{
    public interface PROPERTY
    {
        public static final String NAME = "name";
        public static final String UUID = "uuid";
        public static final String MODIFIED = "modified";
    }

    private String name = null;
    private String uuid = null;
    private String modified = null;

    // Constructor
    public Person ( String nameArg )
    {
        this.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.modified = new DateTime( 2000 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();  // Hard-coding this bogus value for easier reading during experiment.
        this.name = nameArg;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName ( String name )
    {
        System.out.println( "Person object – SETTING 'name' FROM " + this.name + " TO " + name );
        this.name = name;
        String old = this.modified;
        // Calling setter rather than directly assigning value to the member variable so as to enable logging of this action.
        this.setModified( DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString() );
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getUuid ()
    {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @param uuid the id to set
     */
    // Change "public" to "private" to make this a read-only field in Vaadin layout.
    private void setUuid ( String uuid )
    {
        System.out.println( "Person object – SETTING 'uuid' FROM " + this.uuid + " TO " + uuid );
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    /**
     * @return the modified
     */
    public String getModified ()
    {
        return modified;
    }

    /**
     * @param modified the modified to set
     */
    // Change "public" to "private" to avoid FieldGroup re-setting old value. Has another effect: Makes this a read-only field in Vaadin layout.
    public void setModified ( String modified )
    {
        System.out.println( "Person object – SETTING 'modified' FROM " + this.modified + " TO " + modified );
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + this.name + ", uuid=" + this.uuid + ", modified=" + this.modified + '}';
    }

}
```

#### `PersonDetailWindow.java`

```
package com.example.editlistinvaadin;

import com.vaadin.data.Container;
import com.vaadin.data.Item;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup;
import com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.PropertyId;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem;
import com.vaadin.data.util.MethodProperty;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;

public class PersonDetailWindow extends Window
{
    VerticalLayout layout = null;
    FieldGroup fieldGroup = null;

    @PropertyId ( Person.PROPERTY.NAME )
    TextField nameField = null;
    @PropertyId ( Person.PROPERTY.UUID )
    TextField uuidField = null;
    @PropertyId ( Person.PROPERTY.MODIFIED )
    TextField modifiedField = null;

    Button commitButton = null;

    Object itemId = null;
    Item item = null;
    Container container = null;
    Table table = null;

    public PersonDetailWindow ( Object itemIdArg , Item itemArg , Container containerArg , Table tableArg )
    {
        this.setCaption( "Person" );
        this.layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin( true );
        this.setContent( layout );

        // Passing all these objects to facilitate experimentation. Perhaps only the Item is necessary.
        this.itemId = itemIdArg;
        this.item = itemArg;
        this.container = containerArg;
        this.table = tableArg;

        this.layout.setMargin( true );
        this.layout.setSpacing( true );

        this.nameField = new TextField( "Name:" );
        this.uuidField = new TextField( "UUID:" );
        this.modifiedField = new TextField( "Modified:" );

        this.uuidField.setEnabled( false );
        this.modifiedField.setEnabled( false );

        this.nameField.setWidth( 21 , Unit.EM );
        this.uuidField.setWidth( 21 , Unit.EM );
        this.modifiedField.setWidth( 21 , Unit.EM );

        this.commitButton = new Button( "Commit" );
        this.commitButton.addClickListener( ( Button.ClickEvent event ) -> {
            doCommit();
        } );

        this.layout.addComponent( this.nameField );
        this.layout.addComponent( this.uuidField );
        this.layout.addComponent( this.modifiedField );
        this.layout.addComponent( this.commitButton );

        this.fieldGroup = new FieldGroup( this.item );
        this.fieldGroup.bindMemberFields( this );
    }

    private void doCommit ()
    {
        try {
            this.fieldGroup.commit();
            // GOOD: The edited "name" value of "name" in the table row is visibly updated immediately and automatically at this point.
            // BAD: The "modified" field value was updated programmatically on the bean itself in the "setName" method, but there is no way to get that fresh value to appear in the table or the subwindow's detail form.
            // The following suggested "MethodProperty" code does not help. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19077760/642706 and https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/408555/408554
// [
//            Property property = this.table.getContainerProperty( this.itemId , Person.PROPERTY.NAME );
//            if ( property instanceof MethodProperty ) {
//                ( ( MethodProperty ) property ).fireValueChange();
//            }
// ]

            // Dump data from bean backing this updated row in table.
            BeanItem<Person> beanItem = ( BeanItem<Person> ) this.item;
            Person person = beanItem.getBean();
            System.out.println( "Dump Person object just updated & committed: " + person );

            // Nor does this next line show fresh values in "modified" column.
// [
//            this.table.refreshRowCache();
// ]
            // We would close the window at this point, or leave window open for further editing.
            this.close();

        } catch ( FieldGroup.CommitException ex ) {
            System.out.println( "ERROR - Commit failed. CommitException: " + ex );
            Notification.show( "Commit failed." ,
                    "Your changes to this Person record are not yet saved." ,
                    Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE );
        }
    }

}
```

Done. Run the app.

### Solution

One solution is to make the 'modified' member’s setter `private` instead of `public`. This hides the setter from Vaadin. Vaadin interprets that the variable being read-only. The Field on the form will automatically gain the un-editable look on screen. The FieldGroup will no longer try to overwrite its value.

In the example above, look at the Person.java code. Change the scope on 'setModified' to 'private'. Rebuild your project and re-run the app to see the Vaadin Table automatically updated with the fresh 'modified' value.

Change this:

```
public void setModified ( String modified )
```

to this:

```
 private void setModified ( String modified )
```